# Vite library mode generates file with third-party code

Tags: vite

Im creating a components lib and I have a util file that I use throughout the project.

merge.ts:

```
import {clsx,ClassValue} from "clsx";
import {twMerge} from "tailwind-merge";

export function cn(...inputs: ClassValue[]) {
    return twMerge(clsx(inputs));
}
```

But when I'm building my npm package with Vite it generates a file with all imported libraries code. Which is about 3k line of code...

[image]

The "real" merge file just reference the generated one:

```
import { a as r } from "../merge-26328259.js";
export {
  r as cn
};
```

[image]

vite.config.ts:

```
import {defineConfig} from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import dts from 'vite-plugin-dts'
import {libInjectCss} from 'vite-plugin-lib-inject-css'
import {extname,relative,resolve} from 'path'
import {fileURLToPath} from 'node:url'
import {glob} from 'glob'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(),libInjectCss(),dts({include: ['stories/components']})],
  build: {
    copyPublicDir: false,
    lib: {
      entry: resolve(__dirname,'stories/main.ts'),
      formats: ['es'],
      name: "components-lib",
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['react','react/jsx-runtime'],
      input: Object.fromEntries(
        glob.sync('stories/**/!(*.stories.d|*.stories).{ts,tsx,js,jsx}').map(file => [
          relative(
            'stories',
            file.slice(0,file.length-extname(file).length)
          ),
          fileURLToPath(new URL(file,import.meta.url))
        ])
      ),
      output: {
        assetFileNames: 'assets/[name][extname]',
        entryFileNames: '[name].js',
      }
    },
  },
})
```

I have tried to exclude the peerDependencies:

```
  optimizeDeps: {
    exclude: ["react","react-dom","class-variance-authority","clsx","tailwind-merge"],
  },
```

I'm out of ideas and can't find anything good when I google.
Help would be much appreciated!